# How can I invisibly insert my Linux box between work computer and home router?

Tags: networking, vpn, bridge

I am having severe issues using work's Cisco's anyconnect VPN.  My internet connection is fine.  Work's other VPN (non-anyconnect) is fine.  Anyconnect not so fine.  Unfortunately I am supposed to be using anyconnect (otherwise I lose some functionality).  I suspect that it is my ISP that is causing the issues so I want to try to troubleshoot.

My Linux box has an add-in card with 4 ethernet ports currently going idle.  I was wondering if it was possible to achieve the layout in the diagram:

[image: network wiring]

All solid lines are cables:

- Black line (eth0 - router) is the Linux box's normal net connection
- Red line (work PC - router) is current net connection (that I want to replace with...)
- Green lines (work PC - Linux box - router)

My logic is that I can easily wireshark the e4 + e5 portion and not be cluttered with any other fluff from the regular working of the Linux box.

I was thinking that e4 could pretend to be my router (so work PC sees the expected router) and similarly e5 could pretend to be the work PC (so router sees the expected work PC) and the Linux box passively pass traffic from one to the other without any alterations.  I want work PC and router to think it is business as usual.  Only question is I haven't a clue how.  Can anyone give me any pointers to try?

If that idea is a silly idea then how else could this be achieved?

I am not expecting this will fix the issue but feel it would be useful for troubleshooting.

Plus if I can achieve the above then how could I replace the green dotted line to invisibly insert my own VPN (to a public VPN provider maybe a nice wireguard).  I realise that this will mean I would be running anyconnect (a VPN) over another VPN but from the work PC's point of view it shouldn't realise this and from the router's point of view or my ISP's internet connection point of view it would stop it from seeing the anyconnect VPN.  If this works I believe it will point a rather large finger at my ISP (and give me a temporary workround).

Googling has not been a lot of help other than possibly pointing me to needing bridging but I can't fathom out how to setup or if this will allow a VPN to be inserted later.

Any and all advice and guidance appreciated.

Comment: If you make the PC + linux (e4) box, the left hand green line(cable) it own network (say 192.168.7.0/24 and enable ip forwarding on linux and remove the red cable then you have a very conventional setup. You would typically need to set up a small dhcp server on e4. After that you could install whatever tunneling software you want. I suggest you stay away from bridging, it can be made to work but using your linux box as a router is more mainstream.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I still don't know what you meant by "anyconnect not so fine". What is the actual problem you are trying to fix?

Comment: I'd use openconnect rather than any untrusted binary from cisco to connect to cisco.

Comment: You say "pretend to be my router", set it up as a router. (note that your ISP will not use the word router correctly: it is a router / wifi-hub / ethernet-switch / DHCP-server / maybe a DNS-server / etc ). When I say router, I just mean router.

Comment: @icarus - i am wanting to hide from both the work pc *and* the router that the linux box is sat in the middle.  surely if i turn my linux box into a router then this would change the packets passing through.  to start with i just want to monitor the packets.  although i think i can see setting up as a router being something i can try later with or w/o vpn

Comment: @eduardo - anyconnect not so fine means it can, and often does, fail miserably to provide a stable connection.  the *only* thing that appears to continue uninterrupted is voip.  websites + skype + outlook client + rdp all struggle.  sometimes for a second, more often 10s secs and sometimes minutes.  both work and myself are beginning to suspect my isp (works from a 2 x different "home" connections that i have tried)

Comment: @a.b -it is a work pc connecting to work network and stuck with whatever they provide

Comment: Whilst your work PC would know it was connected to a different network, say 192.168.7.0/24 after you set the system up, it wouldn't know that you had your linux box inserted rather than just changing the config of your router to make the LAN be that network. I repeat my advice, set up the linux box as a router. Later you can tunnel traffic destined for the work vpn gateway to an external box so your ISP will not see the actual traffic.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor - "router" is isp provided i.e. all that you listed.  "pretend" is to appear with the "router's" ip + mac, and whatever else is needed, but not do to do *any* "router" tasks.  at this monitoring stage i just want to pass packets unaltered to the real "router".  setting it up as a "router" could be beneficial for changing the packets with or w/o vpn

Comment: To do that I have always used a dump ethernet hub, with a wireshirk PC attached. It looks like what you are trying to do is set up two ethernet ports to act like a layer 2 (ethernet) hub.

Comment: The answer to the title is easy. But your question hides an other other questions after "Plus if...". If you split this question in two I'd happily answer the first one. The second one appears way more fuzzy.